# Are these two subsets of matrices rank-$1$ connected?

Tags: matrices, calculus-of-variations, matrix-rank, svd, singular-values

While solving a problem in calculus of variations, I have reached the following question:

Let $s>0$ be a positive number (in my  application $s>\frac{1}{2}$, but I am not sure if it matters here). Let $M_2$ be the set of all real $2 \times 2$ matrices, and define the following sets:

$$X=\{ A \in M_2 \, |\, \det A=s^2 \,\text{and }\,\sigma_1(A)=\sigma_2(A)=s \}, \, \,\,\,\,Y=\{ A \in M_2 \, |\, \sigma_1(A)=0, \sigma_2(A)=1 \},$$

where $\sigma_1(A) \le \sigma_2(A)$ are the singular values of $A$.

(The point of the condition $\det A=s^2$ in the definition of $X$ is to make $\det A$ positive, i.e. to exclude $\det A=-s^2$).

> **Question:** Do there exist $A \in X, B \in Y$ such that $A-B$ has rank $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ exist iff $s\le1$. We have $X=\{sQ:Q\in SO_2\}$ and $Y=\{uv^T:\|u\|_2=\|v\|_2=1\}$. Hence
$$
\det(sQ-uv^T)
=\det(sQ)-v^T\operatorname{adj}(sQ)u
=s^2-sv^TQ^Tu
\ge s^2-s.\tag{1}
$$
Therefore $sQ-uv^T$ is nonsingular when $s>1$.

When $0<s\le1$, pick any two unit vectors such that $v^Tu=s$. Let $A=sI$ and $B=uv^T$. Then $A-B$ is singular by $(1)$ but it is nonzero because $A$ has rank $2$ but $B$ has rank $1$. Hence $A-B$ is necessarily rank-one. Indeed, as $\operatorname{tr}(B)=v^Tu=s$, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $s$ and $0$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $A-B$ are $0$ and $s$.

Comment: Thanks! That is a great answer; However, I don't understand your last comment: why does $\text{tr}(B)=s$ imply that its eigenvalues are $0$ and $s$? (and how do you deduce the same thing for $A-B$?).  BTW, did you really meant eigenvalues or singular values? Anyway, I understand your argument apart from that. Last question: your characterization of $Y$ follows from considering singular vectors right?

Comment: @AsafShachar (1) The trace of a rank-one matrix is equal to the matrix's only nonzero eigenvalue. (2) Since $A=sI$, each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B$ contributes to an eigenvalue $s-\lambda$ of $A-B$. (3) Yes. If $A=USV^T$ is a SVD, since the two singular values of $A$ are equal to $s$, we have $S=sI$ and hence $A=sUV^T$. As $\det(A)=s^2$, we have $\det(UV^T)=1$ and hence $Q=UV^T\in SO_2(\mathbb R)$. Similarly, if $Y=U\operatorname{diag}(1,0)V^T$ is a SVD, we have $Y=uv^T$ where $u$ is the first column of $U$ and $v^T$ is the first row of $V^T$.